# R Apply by row also sending last column as argument

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to each row of a data frame and at the end of the results it is also printing the final column as well...

I'm not sure why this is the case.

```
df = data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y = sample(1:5,10, replace = TRUE), z = sample(100:105, 10, replace = TRUE))

testprint = function (x){
  print(x[[1]])
  print(x[[2]])
  print(x[[3]])
}

apply(df, 1, testprint)
```

Result:

```
[1] "A"
[1] "2"
[1] "105"
[1] "B"
[1] "1"
[1] "103"
[1] "C"
[1] "5"
[1] "102"
[1] "D"
[1] "1"
[1] "101"
[1] "E"
[1] "3"
[1] "105"
[1] "F"
[1] "1"
[1] "100"
[1] "G"
[1] "3"
[1] "103"
[1] "H"
[1] "2"
[1] "101"
[1] "I"
[1] "3"
[1] "100"
[1] "J"
[1] "1"
[1] "100"
 [1] "105" "103" "102" "101" "105" "100" "103" "101" "100" "100"
```

Comment: The last print is the apply's result. Just use `bla <- apply(df, 1, testprint)` or `invisible(apply(df, 1, testprint))`.

Comment: Yep, thanks... Returning Null now and it's good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `help("function")`:

> If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value
>   of the last evaluated expression is returned.

The last evaluated expression of your function is `print(x[[3]])`.

From `help("print")`:

> print prints its argument and returns it invisibly (via invisible(x)).

And `apply` combines the return values in a vector, which is returned and printed (since you don't assign it).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have use for the return value of `apply`, I don't see a reason to use `apply` at all. You do not seem to use the return value of `print` either, at least in your example. So why not use a `for` loop and `cat`?

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df)))cat(t(df)[,i], sep="\n")
```

Comment: True, I think may have gotten addicted to the apply family... ;)